# Check deployment results

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

I'm deploying a bicep template in a powershell script (in Devops Pipeline) using az deployment group create
The problem is that if the deployment fails, my powershell script just continues instead of immediately failing.
Tried to get the result via this way :
`$deployment_result = az deployment group create`
But the variable remains empty.

Any solution to get a result back so we can check and if necessary throw an exception ourselves?

Regards,
Sven Peeters

Comment: Please share the code you have tried so far? @user23247925

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the deployment results or to handle any conflicts during deployment, use below approaches given with `if`loop using [Comparison operators: `-match`& `-eq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.4#long-description).

*Approach-1:*

```
$deploy = az deployment group create --name newdeploy --resource-group Jahnavi --template-file latest.bicep
$json = $deploy | convertfrom-json                     
 if($json.properties.provisioningState -eq "Succeeded"){
    write-host "Deployment success"
 }
 else{
   write-host "failed"
 }
```

[image]

*Approach-2:*

```
$deploy = az deployment group create --name newdeploy --resource-group Jahnavi --template-file latest.bicep
if($deploy -match '"provisioningState": "Succeeded"'){   
    write-host "deployment success"
 }
else {
    write-host "failed"
 }
```

[image]